# Final Cut Express 3.5 HD quits unexpectedly

Tags: video, final-cut-express

I am running FCE 3.5 HD on a Macbook Pro and whenever I start rendering, it (FCE) unexpectedly quits. Here’s the crash report:

http://inventaweb.net/matthew/fcecrashlog.txt

I have no idea if this will even help, as I have no idea even how to read it...but....

UPDATE: I posted this on another forum and found out that the cross-dissolve transition was causing a problem.

Comment: Glad you got it working! You should post the resolution and a link to the forum as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the cross-dissolve transition that I was trying to render. Technically, I haven't figured out the problem, but now I know what is causing the problem. I am able to render video in other sequences and that works just fine. I haven't tried rendering a cross-dissolve transition in another sequence.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17524/final-cut-express-3-5-hd-quits-unexpectedly